# Is it possible to create a dynamic regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to march hrefs on a web page.

```
\/static\/workout\/[A-Z]{1,4}032812[A-Z]{1,5}-EQB.html
```

I'd like to find a way to make the 032812 portion of the regular expression dynamic, such that the value would reflect the current date. Fore example, on March 31, 2012 the regular expression would look like:

```
\/static\/workout\/[A-Z]{1,4}033112[A-Z]{1,5}-EQB.html
```

I tried creating a string

```
a = \/static\/workout\/[A-Z]{1,4}033112[A-Z]{1,5}-EQB.html
```

and then

```
\ a \
```

but this didn't work. Is there a way of doing this.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use `#{}` just like in a string.

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > some_string = "033112"
 => "033112" 
1.9.2p290 :002 > a_regex = /[A-Z]{1,4}#{some_string}[A-Z]{1-5}-EQB.html/
 => /[A-Z]{1,4}033112[A-Z]{1-5}-EQB.html/
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm kicking myself for not figuring that one out.  thanks again, appreciate your help.

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński This works in Ruby 2.2, but you should be careful if the variable may contain regex characters, consider using `#{Regexp.quote(some_string)}` within `/.../`.

Comment: Be careful when trying to assign a value retrieved by a regex to make a new regex; I made the newbie mistake of accessing the results of `scan` and trying to use that to help make a dynamic regex from other regex results, which even though for my match was only one item, it was a single-item array. So instead of searching for `/thing/` it was searching for `/["thing"]/`!

Answer (score 19):

I fully support Isaac's solution, but you can also:

```
a = "\/static\/workout\/[A-Z]{1,4}" + "033112" + "[A-Z]{1,5}-EQB.html"
regex = Regexp.new(a)
stringtomatch =~ regex
```

Comment: So would it be something like b = Regexp.new(a) and then / b / to perform the match.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. It may also help you put Isaac's answer in the right light.

Comment: To add to that, it's helpful to think of `/` in regexes the way you think of `"` for strings: it allows you to express a regex literal out of some text. Once you have that regex, *applying* it is a separate process that doesn't care much whether the regex came from a literal or some other way of generating regexes. So taking a string and turning it into a regex and then applying it doesn't involve any slashes, just as taking an object, calling `to_s` on it and then printing that string doesn't require any quotes. My example above is just a fancier literal, so it's a different path entirely.