# Ruby on Rails: Checking for valid regex does not work properly, high false rate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I've got a procedure which should check if an input is valid or not. You can set up a regex for this input.

But in my case it returns false instead of true. And I can't find the problem.

My code looks like this:

```
gaps.each_index do | i |
if gaps[i].first.starts_with? "~"
  # regular expression      
    begin
     regex = gaps[i].first[1..-1]
     # a pipe is used to seperate the regex from the solution-string
     if regex.include? "|"
       puts "REGEX FOUND ------------------------------------------"
       regex = regex.split("|")[0..-2].join("|")
     end
     reg = Regexp.new(regex, true)
     unless reg.match(data[i])
     puts "REGEX WRONGGGG -------------------"
     @wrong_indexes << i
     end
   rescue
  end
  else
   # normal string
   if data[i].nil? || data[i].strip != gaps[i].first.strip
     @wrong_indexes << i
    end      
  end
```

An example would be:

```
[[~berlin|berlin]]
```

The left one before the pipe is the regex and the right one next to the pipe is the correct solution.

This easy input should return true, but it doesn't.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thank you all

EDIT

Somewhere in this lines must be the problem:

```
if regex.include? "|"
   puts "REGEX FOUND ------------------------------------------"
   regex = regex.split("|")[0..-2].join("|")
 end
 reg = Regexp.new(regex, true)
 unless reg.match(data[i])
```

Update: Result without ~

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And perhaps, narrow down the question to what does not work.

Comment: Thats somewhere in the middle of my application. there is lots of code around it. 

I have reduced the problem of those lines of code

Comment: I have updated my question a bit

Comment: See https://ideone.com/1nrIbG, it does not compile. Your question is still unclear. Some part of code contains an issue, but what is your `data`?

Comment: data of input is berlin -> and in my minimal regex set up there in the question when I type berlin it shoud say that the input is correct

Comment: the error you found is because of the puts, thats just for console testing

Comment: I also find it hard to see where you want to go. What is the exact input, what are you testing for with the Regexes?

Comment: The exact input is berlin and the regex should test it [[~berlin|berlin]] left of the pipe is my regex code and the right one is the solution. which have to be solved. 

Probably this helps thats the text shown in my application:

Comment: You create a gap by a sequence of strings like text. This will appear as a gap in the question and "text" will be the correct solution. You may use an arbitrary number of variables/gaps. Another option is to use regular expressions: [[~.*]] Regular expressions will be marked with a tilde. To display the correct solution after a false entry, you may use the pipe symbol: [[~regex|solution]] "regex" is an arbitrary regular expression and "solution" is the solution that will be displayed to the learner.

Comment: *The exact input is berlin and the regex should test it [[~berlin|berlin]] left of the pipe is my regex code* - [the `~berlin` regex will never match `berlin` pattern](http://rubular.com/r/8afIqd31SH)

Comment: I tried it without~ ... I've updated the question with the result

Comment: `regex = regex.split("|")[0..-2].join("|")` will result in `regex` equal to `[[berlin`. You need to trim  the `[` and `]`. **See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Lw3yep)**.

Comment: https://ideone.com/Lw3yep

Comment: Thanks that works for the minimal example with berlin|berlin ... but not If I do more complexe regex like /berlin/i|berlin

Comment: You cannot use the regex object as a string. Use a `(?i)berlin` (inline modifiers) (and as for SO comments are concerned, please add `@`+username to let know of the feedback to the user)

Comment: but that worked well in rails 3.2 ... why not it 4.2?

Comment: I have no clue why, but since you already pass `true` as the second parameter to `Regexp.new`, it is already case-insensitive. Why use regex literals if you are using these *strings* inside the Regexp constructor?

Comment: what could be a working alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point is that you are initializing regex using the [`Regexp` constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)

> Constructs a new regular expression from pattern, which **can be either a `String` or a `Regexp`** (in which case that regexp’s options are propagated, and new options may not be specified (a change as of Ruby 1.8).

However, when you pass the `regex` (obtained with `regex.split("|")[0..-2].join("|")`) to the constructor, it is a *string*, and `reg = Regexp.new(regex, true)` is getting `~berlin` (or `/berlin/i`) as a *literal string pattern*. Thus, it actually is searching for something you do not expect.

See, `regex= "[[/berlin/i|berlin]]"` only finds a *literal `/berlin/i` text (see [demo](https://ideone.com/ASODXC)).

Also, you need to get the pattern from the `[[...]]`, so strip these brackets with `regex = regex.gsub(/\A\[+|\]+\z/, '').split("|")[0..-2].join("|")`.

Note you do not need to specify the case insensitive options, since you already pass `true` as the second parameter to `Regexp.new`, it is already case-insensitive.

If you are performing whole word lookup, add word boundaries: `regex= "[[\\bberlin\\b|berlin]]"` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/ExyOel)).

Comment: sorry but that dosn't work ... is there a possibility to change it that way that i can use normal regex?

Comment: if i do \\bberlin\\b --- and I test berin I got false

Comment: @Felix: `berlin` != `berin`. It is not possible to use a string as a literal regex object. You *must* use the Regex constructor and then you cannot use the `/.../`  regex delimiters. See [**Is it possible to create a dynamic regular expression in Ruby**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918231/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dynamic-regular-expression-in-ruby).

Comment: I've seen the regex constructor is obsoelte .. is there something new for rube 2.x

Comment: can you show me an workable example? with full regex support?

Comment: If you mean you want me to hack Ruby regex engine, sorry, I cannot. You should first "convert" the string to the regex object.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm trying .. but Don't know how

Comment: I thought that: reg = Regexp.new(regex, true) will exactly do that

Comment: It will, just make sure the `regex` is a *pattern* string. A regex literal is built  with the help of *regex delimiters* (say, `/.../`) that delimit the action, pattern and modifiers. `actions/pattern/modifiers`. `Regexp.new` expects the *pattern* only. So, adjust the strings you feed to the constructor. That is all there is to it.

Comment: I tried this gem: https://github.com/seamusabshere/to_regexp ... but also not working

Comment: It says *You can also treat strings as literal regexps.* So, it should work for you.

Comment: I thought literels are optional

Comment: Sorry? A regex literal is `regLiteral = /my_cute_pattern/i`, and a pattern string is just `reg_str_pattern = "my_cute_pattern"`.